# Open VCF file on my application, rather than in Address Book

Tags: iphone, ios, addressbook, vcf-vcard

I am creating an Address Book application.  If I have a VCF format, is it possible to be viewed/added in my address book and not on the default address book of iphone?  like having an "open in.. other application" option?
Thanks in advance!